# How to open the iTerm in the sublime text 3?

Tags: terminal, sublimetext3, iterm2

I installed the Terminal package in the sublime3, setting in the package:

```
{
"terminal": "iTerm.sh",
"parameters": []
}
```

But when I press the `command + shift + T` buttons together，there is no response，Why?

Comment: It's a [known issue](https://github.com/wbond/sublime_terminal/issues/89)

Answer (score 18):

For iTerm2 on Sublime Text 3 with [Bond's terminal package](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Terminal) do the following:

- In Sublime 3, go to `Preferences > Package Settings > Terminal > Settings - User`

Paste the following & save:

```
{
    "terminal": "iTerm2-v3.sh",
    "parameters": ["--open-in-tab"]
}
```

Test opening project folder on iTerm2 with `cmd + shift + T` (*Working on Sublime 3 build 3131*)

Terminal package site reference:

[image]

Comment: I have done your recommendation but nothing happens @Syden

Comment: I was able to make it work by using `Keyboard Maestro` and creating a key-binding for `iTerm2`. @Syden

Comment: @alper ok great! just checking if I could help, I have it working exactly as stated above, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Download [this shell script](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wbond/sublime_terminal/master/iTerm2-v3.sh) and add it to your system path with the name `iTerm2-v3.sh`. 
Make sure you have iTerm >= 3.0.4 or even better, latest iTerm2-v3.
Go to `Preferences > Package Settings > Terminal > Settings - User`. Your settings file should look like this.

```
{
    "terminal": "iTerm2-v3.sh",
    "parameters": ["--open-in-tab"]
}
```

Also, double check your shortcut is not overridden by other command. Hit `Cmd+Shift+P` and type `Terminal: Open`

This should work. The iTerm might not get activated, you have to switch to iTerm2 and check if the current folder in Sublime has opened in a new tab in iTerm2.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say without more information. However, a good way to debug such issues is to look in the console. To open the sublime console, press `` Ctrl + ` `` or select View → Show Console from the main menu. Now press the shortcut again and see if some debug message is shown.

If you suspect that something is wrong with the keybinds, you can run `view.run_command('open_terminal')` from the console. This is the command that is issued on `cmd+shift+t` (see the [config file](https://github.com/wbond/sublime_terminal/blob/master/Default%20(OSX).sublime-keymap) of the package).

As a side-note. I didn't know this package existed, instead I once wrote a few lines to do exactly this. It can be useful if you want to play around with running a terminal or such yourself.

```
import sublime_plugin, subprocess

class OpenTerminal(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
  def run (self, edit):
    if self.view.file_name():
      cwd = '/'.join(self.view.file_name().split('/')[:-1])
    else:
      cwd = self.view.window().project_data()['folders'][0]['path']
    subprocess.Popen(['xfce4-terminal', '--working-directory=' + cwd])
```